# Changing Cursor of a Button

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to change the cursor over my buttons on my webpage. I have looked at W3Schools and other websites which say to put cursor: pointer in the css but it's not working.

```css
#button {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1c171c;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 6px black;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" value="Search for Books" onclick="website'" />
```

For some reason the pointer looks like an I when hovering over text and it will not change to the pointer. could it be the (id = "button") part of the html?

Comment: It works even though you call cursor: pointer twice. Doesn't seem like there's an issue here?

Comment: The only issue I see is that you want an `<input>` to be a `<button>`

The appearance of the cursor over the button is a hand, demonstrating that you can click it. 
In your js snippet, if you click on it, you can edit the text. That's great for a search tool, but the way you've designed it's acting like a button, and I can't tell if the desired behavior is to go to some website or to search when the button is pressed, but if you press the button before you can edit the text that just gets confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add readonly attribute to your input.

```css
#button {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1c171c;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 6px black;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" value="Search for Books" onclick="website'" readonly />
```